# JSON object to form a HTML table

Tags: javascript, json

I need to extract values from the below JSON response I am receiving from a web service response.

```
{"ns4:SearchSA_PartyReturn": {
    "xmlns:ns1": "urn:cs-base",
    "xsi:type": "ns4:SearchSA_PartyReturn",
    "ns4:object": {
        "xmlns:ns2": "urn:co-base",
        "recordCount": 3,
        "xmlns:ns0": "urn:cs-rest",
        "ns3:item": [
            {
                "ns3:SA_Party": {
                    "ns3:partyName": "Akorn New Jersey Inc",
                    "ns3:partyStatus": "ACTIVE",
                    "ns2:rowidObject": 20011,
                    "ns3:SAC_Address": {
                        "ns3:item": {
                            "ns3:city": "QUE",
                            "ns3:state": "N",
                            "ns2:rowidObject": 20011,
                            "ns3:postalCode": -4,
                            "ns3:addressType": "P",
                            "ns3:country": "US",
                            "ns3:addressLine": "RD"
                        },
                        "pageSize": 10,
                        "firstRecord": 1,
                        "searchToken": "SVR1.TD3V"
                    },
                    "ns3:partyType": "Pharma",
                    "ns3:SAC_Person": {
                        "ns3:item": {
                            "ns3:firstName": "DO",
                            "ns2:rowidObject": 11,
                            "ns3:lastName": "MA",
                            "ns3:middleName": "R",
                            "ns3:personType": 2
                        },
                        "pageSize": 10,
                        "firstRecord": 1,
                        "searchToken": "SVR1.TD3U"
                    }
                },
                "ns3:changeSummary": {
                    "logging": false,
                    "xmlns:sdo": "commonj.sdo"
                }
            },
            {
                "ns3:SA_Party": {
                    "ns3:partyName": "Akorn New Jersey Inc",
                    "ns3:partyStatus": "ACTIVE",
                    "ns2:rowidObject": 20047,
                    "ns3:SAC_Address": {
                        "ns3:item": {
                            "ns3:city": "SC",
                            "ns3:state": "N",
                            "ns2:rowidObject": 20047,
                            "ns3:postalCode": 12,
                            "ns3:addressType": "B",
                            "ns3:country": "US",
                            "ns3:addressLine": "OTT STET"
                        },
                        "pageSize": 10,
                        "firstRecord": 1,
                        "searchToken": "SVR1.TD3X"
                    },
                    "ns3:partyType": "Pharma",
                    "ns3:SAC_Person": {
                        "ns3:item": {
                            "ns3:firstName": "GE",
                            "ns2:rowidObject": 47,
                            "ns3:lastName": "HA",
                            "ns3:middleName": "B",
                            "ns3:personType": 2
                        },
                        "pageSize": 10,
                        "firstRecord": 1,
                        "searchToken": "SVR1.TD3W"
                    }
                },
                "ns3:changeSummary": {
                    "logging": false,
                    "xmlns:sdo": "commonj.sdo"
                }
            },
            {
                "ns3:SA_Party": {
                    "ns3:partyName": "Cig Na Ltd",
                    "ns3:partyStatus": "ACTIVE",
                    "ns2:rowidObject": 20040,
                    "ns3:SAC_Address": {
                        "ns3:item": {
                            "ns3:city": "JA",
                            "ns3:state": "NY",
                            "ns2:rowidObject": 20040,
                            "ns3:postalCode": 1,
                            "ns3:addressType": "P",
                            "ns3:country": "US",
                            "ns3:addressLine": "QUR"
                        },
                        "pageSize": 10,
                        "firstRecord": 1,
                        "searchToken": "SVR1.TD3Z"
                    },
                    "ns3:partyType": "Insurance",
                    "ns3:SAC_Person": {
                        "ns3:item": {
                            "ns3:firstName": "A",
                            "ns2:rowidObject": 40,
                            "ns3:lastName": "Q",
                            "ns3:personType": 2
                        },
                        "pageSize": 10,
                        "firstRecord": 1,
                        "searchToken": "SVR1.TD3Y"
                    }
                },
                "ns3:changeSummary": {
                    "logging": false,
                    "xmlns:sdo": "commonj.sdo"
                }
            }
        ],
        "pageSize": 10,
        "firstRecord": 1
    },
    "xmlns:ns3": "urn:co-ors",
    "xmlns:xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
    "xmlns:ns4": "urn:cs-ors"
}}
```

Can anyone help me with a javascript/jquery to extract `ns3:SA_Party` with its corresponding children `ns3:SAC_Address` and `ns3:SAC_Person`. (SA_Party is the parent with two children SAC_Address and SAC_Person). I need the underlying attribute, too.

Comment: That JSON is terribly unreadable. I would suggest you put it in a code block by starting each line with four spaces and format it so that each item is on its own line.

Comment: This JSON seems to involve insurance information for someone. Perhaps consider whether the publication of the contents of the response JSON is appropriate...

Comment: It was a mocked up data .. no worries .. but still i have edited so that no one feels bad about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume the `data` variable is a valid JSON object that contains your response

```
var items = data['ns4:SearchSA_PartyReturn']['ns4:object']['ns3:item'];

var mapped = items.map(function(item){ 
  return {
    'SAC_Address':item['ns3:SA_Party']['ns3:SAC_Address'], 
    'SAC_Person':item['ns3:SA_Party']['ns3:SAC_Person']
  }; 
});

console.log(mapped);
```

The `mapped` variable will be an array with Objects containing the `SAC_Address` and `SAC_Person` info.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thank you the help. I tired the above code, but it says a is not defined.. Can you please help me here

Comment: @bbk yeah sorry I prototyped the solution and forgot to change the variable names, I just edited it with the correct answer

Comment: thanks a lot .. this helped me figure out lot of things and i figured out that a needed to be item.. But really a great help :)

Answer (score 1):

The [JSON.Parse()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc836466(v=vs.94).aspx) method will take your raw text and convert it into an object, provided that it is properly formatted JSON. You pass the JSON-formatted string as follows:

```
var jsonString = '{"firstname":"Jesper","surname":"Aaberg","phone":["555-0100","555-0120"]}';
var result = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

Then you can normally refer to each element via the dot notation:

```
var firstname = result.firstname;
```

But since there are colons in the specific elements you are looking for and Javascript doesn't support identifiers with colons in them, you'll need to use bracket notation, as in [@HansStrausl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38575054/4616944)